# How to create more users on Darwin Calendar Server? How can be caldav4j used for the same?

Tags: java, calendar, icalendar, webdav, caldav

I  am using [Darwin Calendar Server](https://www.calendarserver.org/) for creating and reading events for users. But I am able to only use existing users. How can I add more users on the server?

I am playing with [caldav4j](https://github.com/caldav4j), is it possible to  create principals (users, location, group) and store to the server using caldav4j.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no standard for the creation of principals etc in WebDAV ACL/CalDAV.

If you are using LDAP/OpenDirectory as the backend to store the user information (like macOS Server does), you may be able to use LDAP to manage your account database.